# What happens after "V" season 2?

Tags: tv, production, v-2009

The 2009 reimagined series [*V*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(2009_TV_series)) (for *Visitor*) was cancelled after only two seasons. Many shows, especially if they're sci-fi or fantasy shows, manage to wrap up the story in some other way after being cancelled.

As Sheldon Cooper eloquently stated:

[image]

**Was *V* wrapped up in anyway, like in comics or a movie/TV-movie? Has anyone involved with the show explained what happens after season two?**

Comment: There are definitely other sci-fi shows that didn't have a proper wrap-up, like Crusade, Alphas, and Stargate Universe. Heck, Sliders seems to have intentionally created a cliffhanger finale with no planned follow-up. On the other end, Sheldon's point is made with Heroes recently having a mini-series called Heroes: Reborn. Not sure what, if anything, happened with V though.

Comment: There is, of course, [the original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1983_miniseries)) [run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(The_Final_Battle)) [of V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(1984_TV_series)) which may provide you with some sense of satisfaction. (Although that kind of ended after a couple of series as well, so it might just be the exact same problem all over again.)

Comment: "Many"? I'd venture it is rare that such things happen. A handful of examples versus a vast number of shows that didn't get such a follow-up.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm that V from 2009 was a remake of a show from the 1980's. My hunt now is to find out whether they are the same story, and if so, whether the original series had an ending. They also had a comic book concurrently with the TV series.

Sorry unless they write and develop a mini-series, TV series, or movie I don't think we will ever know what was intended. To summarize, the old TV show seems to be the same universe but on a different time continuum. (Think of how the Simpsons are perpetually in the present day).

So the queen in new V is Anna, and her mother, which she killed, was named Diana. In the original series, Diana was the queen, and still lived at the end of the 1980 series. Seems they did a sort of cameo throw back/head-nod/honorable mention to the original series in the 2009 remake but decided to go their own way.

Here's a recap [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_%281984_TV_series%29#Plot) of the final show in the 80's version:

> Just as James and his shock troops corner the Resistance, Phillip orders the Visitors to cease to all hostilities and return to the Mothership. The Resistance discovers that the Visitors have made a worldwide ceasefire and that a majority are retreating from Earth. Via Elizabeth, it is discovered the Leader is coming to Earth to negotiate peace, and he has asked Elizabeth and the Resistance to come to the Mothership.
>
> Diana and James decide to extend the war by arming the energy swords of Phillip and Donovan during a supposedly non-lethal duel. When this attempt fails, Diana blackmails James into attempting to assassinate the Leader by having his troops blowing up the Leader's shuttle. When the destroyed shuttle is revealed as a decoy, Diana stages a coup and attempts to self-destruct the fusion reactors of the Mothership in order to kill everyone aboard and destroying Earth. It is only the Leader, working through Elizabeth telepathically, who is able to stop the self-destruct.
>
> The Leader arrives, Diana and James are captured, and Elizabeth boards the Leader's shuttle to return to the Visitor home world to guarantee peace. The episode and the series ends on a cliffhanger with Kyle stowing away on the shuttle Elizabeth is traveling in, which also has a 'going-away present' from Diana aboard.